# If $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix such that $A^2=A$, how to prove $2A-I$ is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

As stated above, If $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix such that $A^2=A$, how to prove $2A-I$ is diagonalizable?

I found that $(2A-I)(Ax)=Ax$, which means that $Ax$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$. But I do not know what to do next.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, but the symbol `*` has a formatting property on this site. This means that writing "n times n" as `n*n` doesn't always turn out the way you want to. Also, `*` isn't really used to symbolise multiplication outside of programming. Try instead to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math.

Comment: Does $A^2=A$ gives us the fact that $AA^*=A^*A$? Because if $(2A-I)$ is diagonalizable, it must be normal and $(2A-I)^*(2A-I) =(2A^*-I)(2A-I)=4A^*A- 2A^* -2A +I$

so, for $(2A-I)$ to be normal, $A$ must be normal too, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Arthur thank you very much for your improvements

Comment: @Jason They weren't mine. But sure. As long as you study the changes and learn from them for next time, it's all good.

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj We are not necessarily dealing with matrices over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Another way: show that $\Bbb F^n = \mathrm {null}\ \boldsymbol A \oplus \mathrm {null}(\boldsymbol {A - I}) $, where $\mathrm {null}\ \boldsymbol A$ means the space of solutions for linear system $\boldsymbol {Ax = 0}$. Also note that $0,1$ are the only possible eigenvalues for $\boldsymbol A$. Then $\boldsymbol A$ is diagonalizable, so is $2 \boldsymbol {A - I}$.

Comment: @xbh thanks for your help. But why A is diagonalizable can imply 2A-I is diagonalizable?

Comment: @Jason Look at the accepted answer. Same reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $A^2-A=0$, the minimal polynomial of $A$, namely $p(x)\big|x (x-1)$, which implies $A$ is diagonalizable.

Therefore, there exists an invertible matrix $Q$ such that $QAQ^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix.

Now just think about $Q \big(2A-I\big)Q^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I would like to know is there any method that does not use minimal polynomial?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$(2A-I)^2 = 4A^2-4A+I = 4A-4A+I = I$$
so the polynomial $x^2-1$ annihilates $2A-I$. This implies that the minimal polynomial of $2A-I$ divides $x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ and hence splits into linear factors. Therefore, $A$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

The case of characteristic $2$ being trivial, I assume we are working over a field of characteristic different from $2$.

Then compute $(2 A - I)^{2}$, and see what does this tell you about the roots of the minimal polynomial of $2 A - I$.